# Change meaning of the operator "+" in perl

Tags: perl

Currently "+" in perl means addition, in my project, we do string concatenation a lot. I know we can concatention with "." operator, like:

```
$x = $a . $b; #will concatenate string $a, and string $b
```

But "+" feels better. Wonder if there is a magic to make the following do  concatenation.

```
$x = $a + $b;
```

Even better, make the it check the operator type, if both variables ($a, $b) are numbers, then do "addition" in the usual sense, otherwise, do concatenation.

I know in C++, one can overload the operator. Hope there is something similar in perl.

Thanks.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html

Comment: When someone else has to maintain this code, and they find out where you live, then it will not feel better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Perl too offers operator overloading.

```
package UnintuitiveString;
use Scalar::Util qw/looks_like_number/;

use overload '+'  => \&concat,
             '.'  => \&concat,
             '""' => \&as_string;

# Additionally, the following operators *have* to be overridden
# I suggest you raise an exception if an implementation does not make sense
# - * / % ** << >> x
# <=> cmp
# & | ^ ~
# atan2 cos sin exp log sqrt int
# 0+ bool
# ~~

sub new {
    my ($class, $val) = @_;
    return bless \$val => $class;
}

sub concat {
    my ($self, $other, $swap) = @_;

    # check for append mode
    if (not defined $swap) {
        $$self .= "$other";
        return $self;
    }

    ($self, $other) = ($other, $self) if $swap;
    return UnintuitiveString->new("$self" . "$other");
}

sub as_string {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $$self;
}

sub as_number {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return 0+$$self if looks_like_number $$self;
    return undef;
}
```

Now we can do weird stuff like:

```
my $foo = UnintuitiveString->new(4);
my $bar = UnintuitiveString->new(2);
print $foo + $bar, "\n";  # "42"
my ($num_x, $num_y) = map { $_->as_number } $foo, $bar;
print $num_x + $num_y, "\n"; # "6"
$foo += 6;
print $foo + "\n"; # "46"
```

But just because we can do such things does not at all mean that we should:

- Perl already has a concatenation operator: `.`. It's perfectly fine to use that.
- Operator overloading comes at a massive performance cost. What previously was a single opcode in perl's VM is now a series of method calls and intermediate copies.
- Changing the meaning of your operators is extremely confusing for people who actually know Perl. I stumbled a few times with the test cases above, when I was surprised that `$foo + 6` wouldn't produce `10`.
- Perl's scalars are not a number *or* a string, they are *both* at the same time and are interpreted as one or the other depending on their usage context. This is actually half-true, and the scalars have different representations. They could be a string (PV), an integer (IV), a float (NV). However, once a PV is used in a numerical context like addition,  a numerical value is determined and saved alongside the string, and we get an PVIV or PVNV. The reverse is also true: when a number is used in a stringy context, the formatted string is saved alongside the number. The `looks_like_number` function mentioned above determines whether a given string could represent a valid number like `"42"` or `"NaN"`. Because just *using* a scalar in some context can change the representation, checking that a given scalar is a PV does not guarantee that it was intended to be a string, and an IV does not guarantee that it was intended to be an integer.
- Perl has two sets of operators for a very good reason: If the “type” of a scalar is fluid, we need another way to explicitly request certain behavior. E.g. Perl has numeric comparison operators `< <= == != >= > <=>` and stringy comparison operators `lt le eq ne ge gt cmp` which can behave very differently: `4 XXX 12` will be `-1` for `<=>` (because 4 is numerically smaller than 12), but `1` for `cmp` (because 4 comes later than 1 in most collation orders).

  Other languages suffer a lot from having operators coerce their operands to required types but not offering two sets of operators. E.g. in Java, `+` is overloaded to concat strings. However, this leads to a loss of commutativity and associativity. Given three values `x, y, z` which can be either strings or numbers, we get different results for:

  - `x + y` and `y + x` – string concatenation is not commutative, whereas numeric addition is.
  - `(x + y) + z` and `x + (y + z)` – the `+` is not associative as soon as one string enters the playing field. Consider `x = 1, y = 2, z = "4"`. Then the first evaluation order leads to `"34"`, whereas the second leads to `"124"`.

  In Java, this is not a problem, because the language is statically typed, and because there are very few coercions (autoboxing, autounboxing, widening conversions, and stringification in concatenation). However, JavaScript (which is dynamically typed and will perform conversions from strings to numbers for other operators) shows the exact same behavior. Oops.

Stop this madness. Now. Perl's set of operators (barring smartmatch) is one of the best designed parts of the language (and its type system one of the worst parts from a modern viewpoint). If you dislike Perl because its operators make sense, you are free to use PHP instead (which, by the way, also uses `.` for concatenation to avoid such issues) :P

Comment: You can even make it more inefficient by using [`overload::constant`](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#Overloading-Constants) to turn all strings into these monstrous objects :-)